# Hiding a container's textual content but not its child element

Tags: css

In the following example I want to hide "text" (by doing `td { display: none }` for instance) while showing "100" that is the content of the `span` element.

How to achieve that?

```
<td>
    text
    <span>100</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to these answers that was given.

```
td { font-size:0; }
td span { font-size:12px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
td { color: white; }
td > span { color: black; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qkksnkf9/

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. Not sure if it is what you want, but it will get the job done!

```
td{visibility:hidden};

td span{visibility:visible};
```